# .NET Core CORS issue for POST request

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a system that consists of 2 parts: .NET Core 2.1 back-end Web API and Angular 5 front-end. For all POST/PUT requests I've got an error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://BACK_END_PATH/api/documents' from origin
> 'https://FRONT_END_PATH' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

and HTTP status code 401 is returned for the preflight request.

In Angular I use Windows Authentication and send requests with credentials:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // add windows credentials
    request = request.clone({
        withCredentials: true
    });
}
```

I've already turned on CORS for all requests, methods, headers and credentials and checked that CORS is applied before MVC:

```cs
readonly string CorsAllowSpecificOrigins = "_corsAllowSpecificOrigins";

public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services) 
{
    // allow CORS
    services.AddCors (options => {
        options.AddPolicy (CorsAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder => {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .AllowAnyMethod ();
            });
    });

    services.AddMvc (options => {
            options.Filters.Add (typeof (ModelValidatorFilter));
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion (CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    //comment for brevity
}

public void Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) 
{
        //comment for brevity

        app.UseCors (CorsAllowSpecificOrigins);
        app.UseHttpsRedirection ();

        app.UseMvc (routes => {
            routes.MapRoute (
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
}
```

I thought that issue was 'application/json' Content-Type, but the same type is used in Postman and Postman requests are working fine.

Also, I found a solution where anonymous users are turned on, but unfortunately I can't use this trick in my system.

Update1: I also tried to set origin in this way:

```cs
builder.WithOrigins("https://FRONT_END_PATH")
                    .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
```

but the error was the same.

Comment: If you're going to use `withCredentials: true`, then you have to configure CORS on the server with specific origins. `AllowAnyOrigin()` won't do. You have to use `WithOrigins(...)`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware

Comment: It was my previous approach, I set builder.WithOrigins("FRONT_END_PATH")
     .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
     .AllowAnyHeader()
     .AllowCredentials()
     .AllowAnyMethod(); 
and it didn't work.

Comment: Can I assume that `FRONT_END_PATH` is the fully qualified URL for the client application? Protocol, domain and port?

Comment: Yes, it looks like https://www.sitename.com , without slash at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference#cors-preflight-request), you can find following information:

*A CORS preflight request is used to determine whether the resource being requested is set to be shared across origins by the server. And The OPTIONS requests are always anonymous, server would not correctly respond to the preflight request if anonymous authentification is not enabled.*

[image]

To fix this issue, if you run the App(s) on local for testing purpose with CORS, you can try to enable anonymous authentification.

Besides, if your App(s) are hosted on IIS, you can try to install [IIS CORS module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-in-iis) and configure CORS for the app.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I didn't receive any notifications about the answer. I tried to enable anonymous authentification in the web.config, but it didn't work, so I created a ticker for admins to install the IIS CORS module. I think anonymous auth was banned in their configuration. Thanks a lot.