# Angualr & Asp.net core (Cors)

Tags: angular, proxy, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

i have deployed my api project and begin use it in my angualr 17 project
i have enabled the cors in the backend in the program.cs file .
but the problem is if i requested the (Get) it works fine and return me the response but when i tried the (Post) request it show me error in the console is that it's blocked by cors .
what make me confused is when i try the same (post) api on the swagger and postman it works
but why in the anugale is not !! .
i don't know if the version of the .net is make all this but i am using .net core version 7.
also i have tried that using another post api (not from my api -Generic one -) and it works and didn't show me any errors
may it because the site of the cors implementation in my program.cs file !
i have used this in my .net core  api
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

- db Connection

  -- JWT Services

  -- Swagger Implementation

  string allowedOrigin = "http://localhost:4200"; // link of angualr

-- JWT Implementation

```
    policy.AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .WithOrigins(allowedOrigin)
            .AllowCredentials();
```

also i have used the proxy.conig in my anugalr json but it didn't work as well.
my error is
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mydomain/api/User/Login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Comment: Do you think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63706042) your issue? You are hit the `login` request, could you pls help check whether this request is also protect by some authorization scheme? If yes, could you pls make `/api/User/Login` to be `allow Anonymous`?

Comment: by the way, did you use the cors policy in your Program.cs?  put `app.UseCors("{policy_name}");` after `app.UseRouting();`

Comment: i have already used [AllowAnonymous]
also the app.UseCors("{policy_name}"); is alreay after the app.UseRouting();

Comment: is there any proxy between the angular app and the web api? and could you pls share a minimal sample for reproducing the issue?

Comment: i have created a proxy.config.json file in the angualr 
here it is 
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http//myDomain.com/api/",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api":""
    },
    "changeOrigin": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }}
also i have updated the cors in the dotnet api  to 
 builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowCredentials();

Comment: I found a [blog here](https://www.azilen.com/blog/how-to-resolve-cors-errors-by-using-angular-proxy/) which introduce how to use angular proxy to solve the cors issue, which is similar to the configuration you shared. Did you follow them to try to solve the error before and found it didn't work? And if you didn't have the proxy, the cors error still persisted, right? If so, I'm afraid it's better to have a minimal sample for reproducing the issue.

Comment: no surprise that it works in Postman as it has no CORS rules.  Those are enforced by the browser.  Be sure to install the CORS module in IIS.  The error implies that the server is not responding to the browser's OPTIONS request.  Probably better to use the proxy to keep everything same-domain, though.  Then you can avoid reducing the security of the server.